# Remove a specific commit from the repository

Tags: git, github

How can I remove a specific git commit from the repository?
For eg I have commit like A-B-C-D-E and I want to remove the C commit to have A-B-D-E, then how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easisest way I would think is to do `git rebase -i B`, remove the line for C in the text that git presents and save and let git do the rebase. Note that history will become A-B-D2-E2 ( and can never become A-B-D-E)

Note that rewriting history is not always good. If you have published ( pushed) try doing `git revert C` as that is more safe. the history will become like A-B-C-D-E-C'